# .indexOf multiple lines in javascript

Tags: javascript

So i have this code that needs to check for multiple variables so if for ex either id 1 or id 2 is true it plays console.log so i could either make multiple var's or test indexOf mutliple lines and when 1 is true it plays console.log

```
var id = '76561198331632938';
if (document.getElementById("id").innerHTML.indexOf("76561198331632938" || "id2") != -1) { 
    console.log("Hello world!");
}
```

Comment: Why using `||` in indexOf() ?

Comment: i'm trying to test if the <a id="id"> contains a certain word or numbers i got that to work but i need it so it checks for multiple so like either tests for 1 if not found 2 if found 2 excute console log

Comment: No, you have to use 2 indexOf()s. You Can't combine it like that.

Comment: so i should do like .indexOf() + indexOf()

Comment: There is no question in the entire post. I can guess what it is, sure, but that's not the point.

Comment: @Domien. Something like `...indexof("value1") !=-1 || ... indexOf("value2") !=-1`

Comment: You shouldn't think of your targets as lines of text. You see your targets as DOM Objects. If you have divs with ids, then gather them up as a HTMLCollection, covert it into an array, ***then use an array method***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to put `||` outside of `indexOf`:

```
var id = '76561198331632938';
if (document.getElementById("id").innerHTML.indexOf(id) !== -1 || 
    document.getElementById("id2").innerHTML.indexOf(id) !== -1) { 
    console.log("Hello world!");
}
```